# TSQL: Values of all field in a row into one string

Tags: sql, t-sql

i need to put all, not null, values of single row into one string, like

table:

```
CustomerName  Address Zip
Alex          Moscow  1234
```

to result:

```
CustomerName: Alex
Address: Moscow
Zip: 1234
```

Important note - i don't know field names/types, so it should go through all fields and all not null values add to list.

Looks like it can do this using xquery, but can't find right syntax. 
Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select T2.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)')+': '+
       T2.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
from (select *
      from YourTable
      for xml path(''), type) as T1(X)
  cross apply T1.X.nodes('/*') as T2(N)
```

Comment: Thanks, cool, looks like exactly what i am looking for, will try to implement this.

Comment: Hi Mikael, if i have a table with FieldName and FieldDescription for all fields in YourTable - how can i modify this statement to show FieldDescription  instead of field name? Thanks!

Comment: @Alex - You do an inner join against DescriptionTable `inner join DescriptionTable as D
    on T2.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') = D.FieldName` and use FieldDescription in the field list. `select D.FieldDescrption+': '+
       T2.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')`

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'CustomerName: ' + isNull(CustometName, '') + 'Address: ' 
+ isNull(Address, ''), + 'Zip:' + isNull(Zip, '') from [TableName]
```

And maybe you need to cast some values to varchar

Comment: sorry, see Important note, added recently

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant as Mikael's solution. but i still want to include it.

```
DECLARE @yourtable nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(2100)
DECLARE @col as nvarchar(2000)

SET @yourtable = '<tablename>'

SELECT @col = coalesce(@col, '' ) + '+'''+t2.column_name+': '' + cast([' + t2.column_name + '] as varchar) + char(32)'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t1 join 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t2 on t1.table_name = t2.table_name
where t2.is_nullable = 'NO' and t1.table_name = @yourtable
and t1.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and t1.table_schema = t2.table_schema
and t2.table_schema = 'dbo'
SET  @sql = 'select ' + stuff(@col, 1,1,'') +' from ' + @yourtable
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: sorry, see Important note, added recently

Comment: thanks, i also wrote similar code, but then wondered if i can do something like Mikael's solution