# t-sql udf to return concatenated field values for one row in any given table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

I'm looking to create a function where a table name is passed, and an id value, and the procedure returns a single string with all the field values for that specified row.  All tables that could get referenced have a field called 'Id'.  I've found other examples which can concatenate a specified row in a table, but have been unable to find a way to dynamically specify the table.  Below was the closest exampel I found here :

[TSQL: Values of all field in a row into one string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145485/tsql-values-of-all-field-in-a-row-into-one-string)

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_GetTableValues (@TableName varchar(MAX) = '',@Id int = 0)
    RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @returnVal varchar(MAX)

  SELECT @ReturnVal = ''
  SELECT @ReturnVal = @ReturnVal 
         + ' // ' 
         + T2.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)')
         +': '
         + T2.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    FROM (SELECT *
            FROM Branch 
           WHERE ID = 1
             FOR XML PATH(''), type) as T1(X)
   CROSS APPLY T1.X.nodes('/*') as T2(N)


  RETURN @ReturnVal  
END
```

Comment: You can't use dynamic SQL in a TSQL UDF without some crazy workaround using `xp_cmdshell`

Comment: Yup, I found that out when I tried to place the command into a string with the tablename and run a parameterized sp_executesql, was wondering if there was another way to do it dynamically.  Otherwise the only way I could figure of doing it would be a case statement within the above function to run a different query for each table which would a) look ugly, and b)be unwieldy and need modifying every time a new table was added.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, you have to come to grips with the fact that SQL Server refuses to allow dynamic SQL in functions. It's unfortunate, but it is a limitation you must work around.

Here is a technique to apply dynamic SQL logic on each row of a table

- Create a temp table to hold all the input parameters for your dynamic SQL as well as the expected results
- Create a stored procedure that already expects the temp table to exist and loops over the rows of the temp table applying the dynamic SQL logic
- Add the data you want evaluated to the temp table
- Execute your dynamic SQL proc
- Enjoy your expected results :-)

1) Let's start with setting up some test data.

```
    -- ====================================================================
    -- BEGIN: Setup test data
    -- ====================================================================
    IF OBJECT_ID('Branch', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Branch;
    IF OBJECT_ID('Branch2', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Branch2;
    GO
    CREATE TABLE Branch (
        ID      int
       ,Column1 varchar(20)
       ,Column2 varchar(20)
       ,Column3 varchar(20)
    )
    CREATE TABLE Branch2 (
        ID      int
       ,Column1 varchar(20)
       ,Column2 varchar(20)
       ,Column3 varchar(20)
    )
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT Branch SELECT 1, 'Hello', 'World', 'I write SQL'
    INSERT Branch SELECT 2, 'I like', 'it to be', 'complicated'

    INSERT Branch2 SELECT 1, 'Hello', 'World', 'I write SQL'
    INSERT Branch2 SELECT 2, 'I like', 'it to be', 'complicated'
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    GO
    -- ====================================================================
    -- END: Setup test data
    -- ====================================================================
```

2) Next, we'll create a proc that handles the dynamic SQL.

```
    -- ====================================================================
    -- BEGIN: Proc with dynamic SQL logic
    -- ====================================================================
    IF OBJECT_ID('prcReturnTableData', 'P') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE prcReturnTableData;
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE prcReturnTableData 
    AS

    DECLARE @SQL                    nvarchar(MAX)
           ,@ParameterDefinitions   nvarchar(MAX)
           ,@TableName              varchar(128)
           ,@ID                     int
     SELECT @ParameterDefinitions   = '@ID int'      

    DECLARE @idx int
     SELECT @idx = MIN(idx) FROM #Result

    WHILE @idx IS NOT NULL
      BEGIN
        SELECT @TableName = TableName
              ,@ID        = ID
          FROM #Result
         WHERE idx = @idx

        SELECT @SQL = '
            DECLARE @ReturnVal varchar(MAX)

            SELECT @ReturnVal = ''''
            SELECT @ReturnVal = @ReturnVal 
                  + '' // '' 
                  + T2.N.value(''local-name(.)'', ''nvarchar(128)'')
                  + '': ''
                  + T2.N.value(''.'', ''nvarchar(max)'')
              FROM (
                    SELECT *
                      FROM ' + @TableName + ' 
                     WHERE ID = @ID
                       FOR XML PATH(''''), type
                    ) as T1(X)
             CROSS APPLY T1.X.nodes(''/*'') as T2(N)


             UPDATE #Result SET ReturnVal = @ReturnVal WHERE ID = @ID';

        EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL, @ParameterDefinitions, @ID = @ID;

        SELECT @idx = MIN(idx) FROM #Result WHERE idx > @idx
    END
    GO
    -- ====================================================================
    -- END: Proc with dynamic SQL logic
    -- ====================================================================
```

3) Finally, let's execute the proc and get the results we want.

```
    -- ====================================================================
    -- BEGIN: Solution to execute dynamic SQL logic on each row of a table
    -- ====================================================================
    -- Create the temp table that the dynamic SQL proc expects
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Result', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Result;
    CREATE TABLE #Result (idx int IDENTITY(1,1), TableName varchar(128) NOT NULL, ID int NOT NULL, ReturnVal varchar(MAX) NULL);

    -- Popluate the temp table with the rows you want to evaluate
    INSERT #Result (TableName, ID)
    SELECT 'Branch', ID FROM Branch
    INSERT #Result (TableName, ID)
    SELECT 'Branch2', ID FROM Branch2

    -- Results before
    SELECT * FROM #Result

    -- Execute the dynamic SQL proc
    EXEC prcReturnTableData

    -- Results after
    SELECT * FROM #Result
    -- ====================================================================
    -- END: Solution to execute dynamic SQL logic on each row of a table
    -- ====================================================================
```